# Is it possible to perform JOIN operation on two DATAFILES in apache spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am doing some work related to sort shuffling in Spark. I think one map task creates one datafile (data in form of serialized objects) and one indexfile (to point records of that datafile). I want to perform JOIN on two different datafiles (of two different map tasks). Is it possible to do that by changing internal code of Spark?
Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use **union** function provided in `rdd` class to add to `rdd` objects of same type.

For Example:

Let's suppose you have 2 `rdd` objects as shown below,

```
JavaRDD<String> firstFile = sc.textFile("path\to\file");
JavaRDD<String> secondFile = sc.textFile("path\to\file");
```

You can join then using "**union**" function and then assign it to a new `rdd`

```
JavaRDD<String> rdd = firstFile.union(secondFile);
```

Comment: @Coatless and ankit  thank you for your answer. But, that's not my question as i do not want to perform join on RDDs. Internally, Spark creates datafiles & indexfiles. I want join on two datafiles, if it is possible.

Comment: @infor_tech the answer was supplied by AnkitJindal. I merely fixed formatting due to it appearing in a review queue.

Comment: @infor_tech -  what you are try to achieve might be not possible. But using `SparkEnv.get().blockManager().diskBlockManager().getAllFiles()` you can get the shuffled datafiles and indexfiles.